# Include file in directory parallel to public_html

Tags: php

I would like to have a dynamic value in my path that will include a file that is located in a directory other than public_html. When I test

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

I get the following result:

```
/home/domain/subdomain/mydir
```

which is the same as

```
/home/domain/public_html/mydir
```

This is my dev server and the URL is: subdomain.domain.com/mydir/file1

The file I am trying to include is located in

```
/home/domain/include/anotherdir/file2
```

My production server has a different domain and does not use a subdomain: **anotherdomain.com/mydir/file1** which resolves to:

```
/home/anotherdomain/mydir/file1
```

Is there a way to accomplish this dynamic path with PHP without touching server settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!defined('MYHOMEROOT'))
{
    define('MYHOMEROOT',realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../'));
}
include(MYHOMEROOT.'/mydir1/file.php');
```

Above, please change `'/../../../'` to as many "../" paths as you need to backstep.
You can determine that by

```
$testpath=realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../');
echo $testpath;
```

The above presumes Linux.
Thank you,